# Vuetify -remove preview image after cancelling the upload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

i am trying to remove image preview after cancelling, but im having troubles finding the answers online

inserting image

[image]

after canceling

[image]

vue.js

```
   <v-avatar
      size="95">
      <v-img :src="url" />
    </v-avatar>
  </v-flex>
  <v-flex xs8>
    <v-file-input
      v-model="image"
      accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg"
      :rules="imagesize"
      hint="File extentions (.png, .jpg, .jpeg) File Size limits (max: 10mb)"
      placeholder="Upload profile image"
      prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
      outlined
      filled
      @change="Preview_image"/>
  </v-flex>
```

method

```
Preview_image() {
  this.url = URL.createObjectURL(this.image);
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the `url` property in the [`@click:clear`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-file-input/#click:clear) handler in `v-file-input` component :

```
 <v-file-input
   ...
 @click:clear="url=''"
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/qBNgreE)